# Javascript returns 0 when adding all td values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table and I want to add and display the SUM of a td value in a div when a user access the page.

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Value</td>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="d">PHP <?php echo number_format($l['target_daily'], 2) ?></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

And Some javascript to get sum duning page load

```
<script>
$(calculateSumm);

function calculateSumm() {

    var sum = 0;
    $(".d").each(function() {
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }

    });
    $('#result').html(sum);    
};
</script>

<div id="result>//This will display sum values but returns 0</div>
```

What I am lacking here?

Comment: one you are trying to use the `.value` property which td's do not have, you need to use `innerHTML`, second you would still get `NaN` as you have `PHP` in front of the number

Comment: Also, you're adding the value from inside your `<td>` and it includes text, specifically the word `PHP` . This will throw off your math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues are that you're using `this.value`, which `td` elements don't have (`value` is just on `input` elements and similar), and you have `PHP` at the beginning of the text of the cells.

See code comments:

```
$(calculateSumm);

function calculateSumm() {

    var sum = 0;
    $(".d").each(function() {
        // Get the text of the cell
        var val = $(this).text()
        // Remove the PHP at the beginning
        val = val.replace(/^\s*PHP\s*/, '');
        if (val.length) {
            // Parse it
            val = parseFloat(val);
            if (!isNaN(val)) {
                // Add it
                sum += val;
            }
        }
    });
    $('#result').html(sum);    
};
```

The bit where we're replacing the "PHP" could use some extra explanation:

```
val = val.replace(/^\s*PHP\s*/, '');
```

That means: "Match optional whitespace followed by PHP followed by optional whitespace at the beginning of the string, and replace it with an empty string".

---

Side note: There's no reason to wonder what's going wrong with your code. Your browser has a JavaScript debugger built into it, which lets you set breakpoints in your code to pause it, inspect variables, single-step through the code to watch it run, etc. Look in the menus for the "Dev Tools" (F12 and/or Ctrl+Shift+I on most browsers).

Comment: Crowder, your so nice..Well explained answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
$(calculateSumm);

function calculateSumm() {

  var sum = 0;
  $(".d").each(function() {
      sum += parseFloat($(this).text());
  });

  $('#result').html(sum);    
};

</script>
```

The value property is not available for TD elements. So I replaced the **this.value** with **$(this).text()** which uses jquery to get the textual value from the inner part of the td element.

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me.But I have to remove The 'PHP' string.Is there any solution to retain that string.I use  that as a currency sign

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @T.J Crowder

```
<script>
$(calculateSumm);
```

function calculateSumm() {

```
var sum = 0;
$(".d").each(function() {
    // Get the text of the cell
    var val = $(this).text()
    // Remove the PHP at the beginning
    val = val.replace(/^\s*PHP\s*/, '');
    if (val.length) {
        // Parse it
        val = parseFloat(val);
        if (!isNaN(val)) {
            // Add it
            sum += val;
        }
    }
});
//$('#result').html(sum);   
$("#result").html(sum.toFixed(2).replace(/(^\d{1,3}|\d{3})(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:$|\.))/g, '$1,'));
```

};

Now it works.Perfect